# Format Java double with only 2 decimal places without rounding

Tags: java, printf, double

I have variables that are doubles and I want to get the double with only 2 numbers after the decimal point. I tried it with

`System.out.printf("%1.2f", number1);`
but the decimal places get rounded. For example if I have number1 = 19.867, I just want to get 19.86 and not the rounded version 19.87. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure the format string supports truncation but you can to it on your own. A simple way might be to do `(int)(number1 * 100)/100.0` (this might suffer from some precision issues though). A safer option would be to use `BigDecimal` with it's `round()` method and providing a proper `RoundingMode` to the `MathContext`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` with an apropriate pattern and a `RoundingMode` to specify rounding behavior:

```
double number1 = 19.867;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

System.out.println(df.format(number1));
```

The same can be achieved by converting the double value to `BigDecimal` and use `BigDecimal`‘s `setScale()` method with a `RoundingMode`

```
BigDecimal bigDecimalNumber1 = new BigDecimal(number1).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(bigDecimalNumber1.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Note: one subtle difference between `DecimalFormat` (and `printf()`) solutions compared to `BigDecimal`: the first ones use the default `Locale` to format the number, while `BigDecimal` does not (e.g. for some countries the first will return a comma `,` as decimal point, while the later one always uses a point `.` {AFAIK})